# Missing argument Laravel controller function edit

Tags: php, html, web, laravel-4

**I have a problem with this**

> I have un list of articles, and each element has a button to edit, how the next code:

```
<p><a href="edit?{{$element->idarticle}}" class="btn btn-primary">modifier l'article</a></p>
```

and I'm sending  to the file route:

```
Route::get('/edit', 'ArticleController@edit');
```

to the file ArticleController method edit:

```
public function edit($idarticle)
{
    $artic=article::find($idarticle);
    if(is_null ($artic))
    {
        App::abort(404);
    }
    $form_data = array('route' => array('article.update', $artic->idarticle), 'method' => 'PATCH');
    $action    = 'modifier';
    return View::make('article.create')->with('artic', $artic);
}
```

then I don't understand my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably change `Route::get('/edit', 'ArticleController@edit');` to `Route::get('/edit/{idarticle}', 'ArticleController@edit');`

Also

```
<p><a href="edit?{{$element->idarticle}}" class="btn btn-primary">modifier l'article</a></p>
```

needs to be

```
<p><a href="edit/{{$element->idarticle}}" class="btn btn-primary">modifier l'article</a></p>
```

The parameter in the router is not passed as an html parameter, but rather a part of the URL. So combines these two changes, it should be working.

Comment: hmmm...can you also try add where constraint?

Comment: of the model Article
say you?

Comment: I just mean add     '->where(array('idarticle'=>'[0-9]+'));'      after           Route::get('/edit/{idarticle}', 'ArticleController@edit')

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Is the error you are describing is "$idarticle" is null inside "edit" function? So the function was called, but parameter was null.

Comment: I tried this that you said Route::get('/edit/{idarticle}', 'ArticleController@edit')-> where (array (' idarticle '=>' [0-9] + '));

but not working

Comment: yeah is this my problem  is null. and I don't understand why?

Comment: Can you confirm the function was called so that I can focused on checking other errors?

Comment: Can you also type url directly into your browser, so like http://localhost/edit/12 and check whether the parameter is passed into the function?

Comment: I get this http://localhost/mini-blog/public/edit?idarticle=4 but isn't pass into the function

Comment: And you have already applied Route::get('/edit/{idarticle}', 'ArticleController@edit')-> where (array (' idarticle '=>' [0-9] + '));, right?

Comment: Ohhhh, I know, the url is not ?. It should be localhost/mini-blog/public/edit/4

Comment: but if I utilise the url localhost/mini-blog/public/edit/4, the error is Method [where] does not exist on view.

Comment: You can remove the 'where' function for now. It is just a validation for passed in parameter.

Comment: ok, I've refreshed my server and the next error is this Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `article` where `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '4', ))

Comment: Awesome. So you actually can get the data now. Hay yay!

Comment: je je I'm amateur in laravel

Comment: and into the ArticleController I have: $artic=article::find($idarticle);, if I change idarticle by id the only error is Undefined variable: id. why is this?

Comment: You probably need to create a new question and list the article model so we can help. Seems now it is a different problem.